# How to convert old script to declarative schema / data patch without breaking any data?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, setup-upgrade, declarative-schema

I have a module (`v1.0.1`) with an `InstallSchema` to create a table and an `InstallData` to create a product attribute.

Now I want to update the module (`v1.0.2`) to convert the `InstallSchema` to the declarative schema (for table creation) and `InstallData` to Data Patch (for attribute creation).

**My question here is:**
How do we perform the upgrades safely for the customers who are already using `v1.0.1` and want to upgrade to `v1.0.2`? so that there are no errors like table/column/attribute already exists

Answer (score 0):

you can try things like taking **DB backu**p , and after converting the setup scripts to declarative schema you will eventually run setup:upgrade , by that time you can try this command like =
**bin/magento setup:upgrade --safe-mode=1** ,
and if things go wrong you can easily revert by executing this command **bin/magento setup:upgrade --data-restore=1**

Comment: Note that I have already converted setup script to db-schema/data-patch. My only concern is what to consider so that the old customer can use this upgrading version without breaking anything.

Comment: The only guess i can think of is to test it out by yourself like creating a new account all in a local development environment, and primarily first check if the data like customer attribute values are already present or not after the changing to declarative schema.If this is not the answer you are looking for , very sorry i was unable to help you , but please do educate me about your solution.Thank you.